# Run CyberGhost at boot on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, vpn, cyberghost

I've subscribed to cyberghostvpn. I'm actually running an ubuntu 20.04 server with gnome-desktop. I'm able to start the vpn by running the following command in the terminal

```
sudo cyberghostvpn --openvpn --country-code IT --connect
```

of course, it asks for password authentication

For the installation, I followed [this guide](https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020436274-How-to-Set-Up-CyberGhost-VPN-CLI-App-on-Linux)

What I've tried till now is using systemd.
I've created a script vpn.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cyberghostvpn --country-code IT --connect
```

I've chmod it to let it be executable.

I've then created a vpn. service into /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN start
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/Documents/vpn.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally I have to enable the service with

```
sudo systemctl enable vpn
```

Before doing this I've tried if everything works correctly and what I've obtained as result is an error like the following

```
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

I believe I've done somthing wrong but I don't know what.

Many thanks fo any help

Comment: Can you pipe the password to cyberghostvpn? I mean, does `cyberghostvpn --country-code IT --connect | echo "<Password here>"` work? As far as I know it doesn't have an option for a password. The problem most likely is that the VPN prompts for password, but since it is in a service you can't answer it. You can use `systemd-ask-pass` for that, but first you have to see if there is any way to feed the VPN the password (via pipe, or option, or environment variable, or something else..)

Comment: Edited. there is no spaces in the path.  The password is the root ones while I'm lounching that command on terminal. In systemd I believe it is not needed